# Database is null, cannot complete login page! (HashMap)

Tags: database, authentication, hashmap, passwords

This is my database:

```
public class Database {

    private Map<String, String[]> cardPinMap = new HashMap<>(); 
    
    public void addCardInfo(String name, String cardNumber, String pin, String bal) {
        cardPinMap.put(cardNumber, new String[] { pin, name, bal });
    }
    
    public String getPinByCardNumber(String cardNumber) {
        String[] cardData = cardPinMap.get(cardNumber);
        if (cardData != null) {
            return cardData[0]; // Index 0 corresponds to the PIN
        }
        return null; // Card number not found
    }

}
```

When I try to add components from my `AddUse`r class via:

```
Database data = new Database(); data.addCardInfo(nmField.getText(), atmField.getText(), pinField.getText(), balField.getText());
```

And check for pin via this function:

```
private Database database;  `

public boolean checkPin(String cardNumber, String enteredPin) {       `

String actualPin = database.getPinByCardNumber(cardNumber);         `

return actualPin.equals(enteredPin);   

`}
```

It says that cardData is null, but I added all of the variables in correctly.

Basically I need the pins to be equal so It could open my home view.

I tried many things but I am stuck and need help, everything seems fine by the code but it does not work.

Comment: I fixed it, I only needed to put static in private Map<String, String[]> cardPinMap = new HashMap<>(); AHAHAHAHAHAH

Comment: Well, then you should add this comment as an answer. This will remove your question from the unanswered question stack. It may be useful for other users seeking for the same issue.

Comment: Sorry I am new to stackoverflow, I just did what you said. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I only needed to put `static` in `private Map<String, String[]> cardPinMap = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: I tried to mark your code properly, but I'm not 100% sure what you intend to say. Please read [answer] and then [edit] this to clarify.